# What does it mean for an improper integral to exist even though it diverges

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have been working through problems in Spivak Calculus and in Chapter 14, (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) Problem 26 it asks if the Integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$ exists.
Now I thought it doesn't because it diverges because the function is unbounded on the interval 0 to 1 by the p-test and comparison, even though from 1 to infinity it converges for the same reason.

But the answer says it exists because it exists from 1 to infinity because it converges on that interval.

I would be grateful if someone could explain this meaning to me.

thank you very much!

Comment: The integrand is bounded above by $1$ and below by $0$ on the interval $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @brenderson thank you. I think I am misunderstanding something then. I thought it's unbounded near 0.

Comment: @brenderson thank you I see my fault now, I did a bad comparison because the + 1 keeps it bounded.

Comment: Thanks to brenderson's comment above I found my mistake. I made a bad comparison, as the +1 under the root ensures that the fraction is less than 0 and the integrand is also bounded from 0 to 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition an integral is improper when either:

- we have $\pm\infty$ as "endpoints" of the interval of integration
- the function is not bounded on that interval

In that case, as already noticed in the comments, we have a bounded function but the integral is said improper because we have $\infty$ as upper limit, that is

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}=\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_0^a \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1+x^3}}$$

which converges since

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^3}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}$$

and

$$\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_1^a \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x^3}}=\lim_{a\to \infty} \left(-\frac{2a}{\sqrt{a^3}}+2\right)=2$$